# Keeping only the latest revision in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some text with revisions and some without revision in excel. I want to only keep the revision with the highest number. For example in the sample picture below. I want to include "002001" as it is unique but in case of "002050" I have 2 set of data one without the revision and one with the revision, in this case I want to keep "002050_R02" since it's the highest revision. How do I accomplish this in excel without the VBA.

[image]

Comment: sort by ID then test the left 6 characters to see if they match the 6 left of the string below.  If they match return `N` if they do not match return `Y`

Comment: Are you saying you have marked all older version with 'N'? If so, do you possibly have `FILTER()`? Or is this the desired results? Another question; are the ID's always six characters, and; are newer versions always below the older one in the current order?

Comment: @ScottCraner - I also have scenarios where I will have up to 20 revisions (_R20).

Comment: It should not matter, as if you sort them the bottom one will always be the one you want to mark `Y` and the formula: `=IF(LEFT(A2,6)=LEFT(A3,6),"N","Y")` will take care of it.

Comment: @JvdV  This is the desired result. No the ID's before "_R00" are not always 6 characters. Yes I have sorted them so the current one is always at the bottom.

Comment: Then sort it and use: `=IF(LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({".","_"},A2&"_"))-1)=LEFT(A3,MIN(FIND({".","_"},A3&"_"))-1),"N","Y")`

Comment: @ScottCraner the formula works perfectly for 6 digits, I also have some with this format "7AB141682_R00"

Comment: @ScottCraner This formula works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort column A.

Then use:

```
=IF(A3<>"",IF(LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({".","_"},A2&"_."))-1)=LEFT(A3,MIN(FIND({".","_"},A3&"_."))-1),"N","Y"),"Y")
```

And copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know it deviates from your desired results, but I figured it would just be an intermediate step. So if available try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=UNIQUE(XLOOKUP(LEFT(A1:A8,FIND("_",SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,".","_"))-1)&"_*",SUBSTITUTE(A1:A8,".","_"),A1:A8,,2,-1))
```

---

Just for fun an alternative in older versions to get the `Y` or `N` values:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2,LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({".","_"},A1&"_.")-1))&"_*"),"N","Y")
```

Might work right?

Comment: I get a Name error with your formula. You are right it's an intermediate step.

Comment: @JamesSmith. Then don't worry about my answer as you probably don't have ms365. I did add an alternative for older versions but it may look a bit cumbersome.